# Scribd api embed android browser not working

Tags: android, html, api, scribd

The mobile html5 viewer for scribd docs does not seem to work on android devices
I have tested with a Galaxy S3 on chrome mobile and native browser but I just get a blank page.

I am using the api to get the full screen url for a doc for mobile device.

Example url:
http://www.scribd.com/mobile/doc/141433311/embed?access_key=key-71ujrg34qhhsvdzavyk

Works on Iphone but not android.

Am I the only one to have this issue?

Thanks
Nic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just an issue with the document not listed as a public document in scribd...